# How to find if a function returns a certain value for a certain amount of time in c++ ??

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a project wherein I am converting different body gestures of user into voice. Whenever the user makes a gesture the gesture recognition function returns a certain value else it returns zero. However I don't want the program to misfire so I want to check if the function returns that particular value for a certain amount of time. I know I can use delays or counters to do this but is there a more efficient way to do this in c++/visual studio ??
   I want to do something like this

```
     if (gesture_function==somevalue_for_some_milliseconds)
```

I know I can do this 
       if(gesture_function==value)
        delay_ms()
       if(gesture_function==value)
         Yes gesture was made
       else 
       gesture was not made

Cheers......

Comment: Presumably you have some thread getting new frames from the camera and calling some gesture recognition function on them: that thread must either be getting "call backs" from your camera API or blocking between frames.  Either way, you can keep a counter of the number of frames yielding the same gesture - if the gesture changes overwrite the "lastest_gesture_seen" variable and reset the counter to 0.  When the counter reaches some value act on it.  If it's flakey, you might use a circular buffer and tolerance e.g. if 8 of the last 10 gesture functions yield the same value you honour it.

Comment: what do you mean by `more efficient way`? more efficient in programming time, more efficiernt in memory ressources, more efficient in execution time or more "efficient" concerning robustness/quality?!?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a command which does this.
 for example as in opencv we have 
                                WaitKey(delay)=="KEYVALUE"
By doing this I can find if a key was pressed for some time(given by delay)  and proceed accordingly

Comment: afaik there are no OS or hardware solutions to observe a memory location for changes, but it should be easily implemented if you create a class and use getters and setters ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just poll every or so milliseconds and then create a large array that will be used to create a moving average?

Convert gesture recognitions into either true or false every 100 milliseconds
-> Store up to 50 values in an array
-> Check the average of all the values to be above **T**, such that **T** is the tolerance factor between 0.00 and 1.00.
-> If moving average > T, then the gesture was recognized.